# Intersection of infinite sets of powers of two.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have sets such that contain all the powers of two to a natural number. The first set would contain all powers of 2 to the 1st, the second would contain all the powers of 2 to the 2nd, and so on. So each set is infinitely large, and there are infinitely many. Intuitively, I believe the intersection of all these sets is not empty- is that true? And if so, how do I prove it?

Edit: To clarify, $S_1=\{2^1,2^2,2^3,2^4...\},S_2=\{(2^2)^1,(2^2)^2,(2^2)^3,(2^2)^4...\},S_3=\{(2^3)^1,(2^3)^2,(2^3)^3,(2^3)^4...\}$

Edit2: So more generally, $S_n=\{(2^n)^1,(2^n)^2,(2^n)^3,(2^n)^4...\}$

Final Edit: Thanks to Rushabh Mehta down below, I realize my mistake. I thought that for every set, there would be an element whose exponent was a multiple of all lower n's. But, as we go to infinity, there is no x that is a multiple of all natural numbers. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is not at all clear.  It looks like each of your sets has finitely many elements.

Comment: The sets you describe are not infinitely large, they each have one element. Further $\{2^1\}\cap \{2^2\}=\{\}$ so clearly $\bigcap_{k\in\Bbb N} \{2^k\}=\emptyset$.  So some clarrification is needed.

Comment: Do you possibly mean something like $S_1=\{2,2^2,2^3,2^4,\cdots\}$, $S_2=\{2^2,2^4,2^6,\cdots\}$,$S_3=\{2^3,2^6,2^9,\cdots\}$ and so on?  If so, then sure these sets are each infinite but clearly their intersection is empty since $2^n$ isn't in $S_k$ when $k>n$.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm confused. How does that fact make the intersection empty? Every single set of this form will have a common element, being two raised to the least common multiple of [n]. The fact that the first element of a smaller n set won't be in larger n sets doesn't mean other elements cant be in both.

Comment: @DanielGarcia: Didn't you say you're taking the intersection of _all_ your sets? By definition, nothing that's missing from even one of the sets can be in that intersection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sets you are defining are more concisely described as the following $$S_n=\{2^k\;|\;k\%n=0\}$$where $\%$ refers to the mod operator. It is clear that $\forall x\in\mathbb{N}\;\exists n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x\%n\neq0$, so $2^x\notin S_n$. Hence, $$\forall x\in\mathbb{N}\quad 2^x\notin\bigcap\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}S_n$$which implies $$\bigcap\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}S_n=\varnothing$$

Comment: I think I understand. So since there is no x that is a multiple of all natural numbers, there is no element that is in all the sets. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The smallest member of $S_n$ is $2^n,$ which is greater than $n.$ If $x$ belonged to each $S_n$ then $x$ would be greater than or equal to the least member of each $S_n$ so $x$ would be greater then each $n.$

This would require  $x$ to be a positive integer that is greater than every positive integer , which is absurd.